# What is the difference between these types of arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I just found out that you can add more parentheses to an arrow function. What is the difference/benefits?

```
const func_a = () => {}

const func_b = () => () => {}

const func_c = () => () => () => {}
```

Comment: A new arrow function?

Comment: Functions can return functions